# Responsive Navbar Hemberger click function dose not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

the code  somehow does not work in responsive mode I've tried in 600px screen the hamburger button won't work(I click it and nothing happen )  I reviewed both the CSS and js over and over couldn't figure the problem maybe because I'm just a beginner and can't know something is wrong even if I'm looking at it  a provisional view would be helpful

```js
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0]
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Calibri Light";
}

.brand-title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}
.navbar-links ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.navbrar-links li {
  list-style: none;
}
.navbar-links li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
}
.navbar-links li:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.75rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30px;
  height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .toggle-button {
    display: flex;
  }
  .navbar-links {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .navbar-links ul {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .navbar-links li {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar-links li a {
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  }
  .navbar-links:active {
    display: flex;
  }
}
/* Full navbar menu */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="brand-title">Brand Name</div>
        <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-links">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="/scrpit.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to use classname rather than the :active CSS pseudo-class.

The line where you have

```
.navbar-links:active {
```

Replace : to . as followed:

```
.navbar-links.active {
```

and it should work.